# Better earphone sound quality between these two

Tags: headphones, earphones

I'm confused between JBL **Tune 205** and JBL **C200SI**.

T205 has a bigger driver size (12.5 mm) and C200SI has 9 mm but I'm not sure if it affects sound quality or not.

Further, impedance of C200SI is also low, which I feel doesn't affect sound quality as it is responsible for how much power needed to play any music/sound. (It means it can operate on lower power too, maybe)

There are other parameters too, but I can't decide between both of them:

**C200SI:**

[image]

**T205:**

[image]

**So any idea which one of them theoretically should give better sound quality?**

Comment: Audio quality can only be determened by listening to them side by side. Reviewers on YouTube are the best way to gather information, then specs.

Comment: Larger speakers can reproduce lower frequencies better. So if you like bass response from your music you might find it sounds better with the T205. Also, impedance *does* affect sound quality if the device powering the headphones can't provide enough power. Since they're both pretty low impedance this doesn't matter, but sometimes you might find 100+ ohm headphones that won't be properly powered by a mobile phone.

Comment: Aside from the driver size, the specs are pretty much the same. The first comment is right, you will have to try them both to really know which sounds "better". "Better sound quality" is extremely subjective and everyone has a different opinion of what that means too.

Comment: @Romen now I have both. Bass is better in C200SI  and voice quality is different in both. But I can't figure out which one has better voice. Really can't decide. Try listening things alternatively on both. Voice is different but can't decide which one is better.